# Nginx Proxy_Pass to CDN vs hitting CDN directly. Pro's, Con's, Is it slower or are there negative effects on the server?

Tags: linux, proxy, nginx, cdn, reverse-proxy

### Situation

CDN's are great but I found a need to dynamically populate files into one. Below I describe how I setup NGINX to do this. My question is `Is it any slower or are there any performance issues for doing a proxy_pass to a resource than hitting the resource directly`? For example.. proxy_pass via URL to http://domain.com/file.jpg vs loading http://domain.com/file.jpg directly. Also, `are you saving any server server resources by doing a proxy_pass to another image location vs simply serving up the image`?

### What I did

I setup a Nginx server so a request to *http://domain.com/image/XYP.jpg* would do a Proxy_pass to a CDN, effectively loading *http://cdn.com/XYP.jpg*. I configured Nginx to check to see if there was an error code and then do something else. IF (error page) 404, nginx can pass you to a local resource which then might trigger the creation of the file on the CDN.

Next time, you request *http://domain.com/image/XYP.jpg*, you'll be accessing the CDN.

## So the steps are :

- Request Attempt # 1 for `xyz.jpg`
- Proxy_pass to CDN
- If File 200, load file : If 404, load local file
- Trigger file generation of `xyz.jpg` on CDN
- Request Attempt # 2 for `xyz.jpg`
- Proxy_pass to CDN
- File exists (200).. load file from CDN indefinitely and not locally

## Technology being used

- PHP
- Ubuntu
- Nginx
- CDN

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't much point in proxy_pass to a CDN. When you consider what proxy_pass does, it should be apparent.

proxy_pass simply means Nginx says to the backend (CDN in your case) fetch the resource and return to me so that I can serve it to the client.

So in your case, what is happening is ...

1. Client makes request for x.jpg
2. Nginx resolves location of CDN
3. Nginx asks CDN for x.jpg
4. CDN sends x.jpg to Nginx
5. Nginx receives and buffers x.jpg etc
6. Nginx forwards x.jpg to client

The round trip to the CDN is essentially a waste since Nginx still has to send the file to the client. Far better to just send it directly ...

1. Client makes request for x.jpg
2. Nginx gets x.jpg from local disc
3. Nginx sends x.jpg to client

If you want to use a CDN, then you should ***redirect*** the request to the CDN ...

1. Client makes request for x.jpg
2. Nginx redirects client to CDN
3. CDN sends x.jpg to client

Obviously, you will not be able to do the 404 test in the case of the redirection as Nginx is no longer involved in the transaction after the redirection.

Comment: Any ideas about how you might do the 404 OR exists test? I'm working with dynamically sized images. So ultimately, I want check if that image has been created and loaded on the CDN. If it hasn't then create it and load it on the CDN for the next request.

Comment: I found another angle might be looking into something called CDN Pull Origin. It's the CDN-side version of what I was trying to do. I think it will work much better.

Comment: Great if that works. What I have done in a similar situation is to let the application (PHP) check the CDN when creating the webpage and then put a url based on this. I also store a flag and the process is that app checks if flag is present. If present, use CDN url. If no flag, send head request to CDN. If 200, use CDN url and create flag. If 404, use local url. The first person to visit such a page will face delays due to the the head requests. You can trigger the resource creation if 404 in your case and serve local resource for that time (I have to manually upload in mine so not an option)

Comment: What you need to use here would be an S3 bucket: 
http://www.labnol.org/internet/tools/amazon-s3-buckets-tutorial/3890/